# click event to enable and disable layer in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, function, button, click, leaflet

I have a group layer "classes" that I want to enable and disable with a click event on an easybutton enabled in leaflet.js. Thus far I have not had success getting the layers to enable.

My code:

```
    L.easyButton('fa-pencil', function(){
    classes.addLayer({
        click: onClick
    });
}).addTo(map);

function onClick(e) {
    map.removeLayer(classes);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661092/simplify-the-toggling-of-layers-on-and-off-in-a-custom-control-with-checkboxes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I saw that example but I'm having trouble seeing how that fits into my code which utilizes EasyButton.

Comment: See what OP did in his/her `$(".check").change` function, compared to your `onClick`. But looks like your `addLayer` is also very weird.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure now. I have tried this also to no avail:          'code' var classes_button = L.easyButton('fa-pencil', function(){
          if (map.hasLayer(classes)){
               map.removeLayer(classes);
          } else {
                map.addLayer(classes);
            }
    //     break;
 } 'code'

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce your issue on JSFiddle?

Comment: I tried, fiddle seems to be having trouble though on the output, maybe because it's using leaflet: https://jsfiddle.net/3533vx6k/6/

Comment: You have HTML code in the end of the JS section. Make sure you link to network resources (see your `easybutton.js`). With JSFiddle, you can use the "External Resources" panel on the left, instead of using `script` and `link` tags in the HTML section.

Answer (score 0):

Solution uses hasLayer and a simple if/else statement:

```
var class_button = L.easyButton('fa-pencil', function(){
            if (map.hasLayer(classes)) {
                map.removeLayer(classes);
            } else {
                map.addLayer(classes);
            }
        });

class_button.addTo(map);
```